# Missing argument 1 for my function

Tags: php, class, arguments

Here's my class:

```
<?php
    class eshop_log extends baseDB {


        function insert($tel,$eshop_id,$log) {

            $this->insert();
        }

    }

?>
```

And here's how I using it:

```
$tel=  $_POST['telephone'] ;
$id= $_POST['id'] ;
$log="log";
$e_l= new eshop_log();
$e_l->insert($tel,$id,$log);
```

Why am I getting Missing argument 1 for eshop_log::eshop_log()??

Thanks a ton

Comment: If you want to access the parent insert function, use `parent::insert()`. Now you're making an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with your `baseDB` class. Look into this class, how does the constructor look like? If there is something like:

```
public function __construct($var) {

}
```

you need to pass a parameter to the constructor:

```
$e_l = new eshop_log($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside

```
function insert($tel,$eshop_id,$log)
```

you call again this `insert()` method without passing any arguments.

You have to check, what arguments has parent's `insert()` method.

However, calling parent's method should looks like:

```
parent::insert();
```